# PHP Posting a combo box value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, combobox

If I have a combobox like this:

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option>
 </select>
```

So when I post using:

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
```

I will get M or F as the result for $gender, how do I get both M, F and Male,Female?

Comment: Why do you want both? Also, no, you can't; the `post`ed value is the one selected.

Comment: The reason I want both is because and M or F will be writing to the database, but Male or Female will be display on the screen for the user on whatever they have selected. the gender is just an example, I have a list of like 100 items on the combobox, and it is not wise to write out each item on the php too, so just thinking if it is possible to get the Display Value part.

Comment: I agree with JamWaffles, plus how would you reference this second value? The key 'gender' can only contain one value unless you reformat the data to an array with Javascript, which seems odd since you can just do something on the server side to fetch the long version based on the short version.

Comment: Where on the screen are you wanting to display this? And is it before or after your user submits the form?

Comment: I would like to display that after I submit the form.

Answer (score 5):

As JamWaffles has said, there is no easy way to do this.

However, you do have a few options if you must:

- Option 1 - Use jQuery to post the form for you. You could get the
  `val()` ("M"/"F") of the combo box and also the `html()` value
  ("Male"/"Female").
- Option 2 - Set the value to something like `value="M|Male"` and then
  use `explode()` to get each value separately ("M"/"Male").
- Option 3 - Just use a simple if/else statement on the posted page -
  `if($val == "M") $gender = "Male";`

Comment: Seems like Option 1 is more a suitable option for me, as I am using jQuery to do the posting anyway, let me try that and see what happen...

Comment: If you do go with option 1, don't forget that people without javascript enabled wont be able to submit your form. I would recommend option 2 or 3.

Comment: Personally, I'd post `Male` or `Female` into the database and just `substr()` it when I need `M` or `F`.

Comment: @Jam, there are loads of ways around what the OP is trying to do, its been made into a more complicated task than it needed to be!

Comment: @Prisoner Definitely! The only good use case for `M` and `F` is in a space-confined area, but that's rather rare.

Answer (score 1):

Male and Female are simply display values, the actual value that gets posted is either M or F. You can either use a simple

```
if $_POST['gender'] == "M" { $fullGender = "Male" } else { $fullGender = "Female" }
```

on the server side, or add a new hidden field to the form and update it when the gender select box changes, ie

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=gender]").change(function() {
        $("#fullGender").val($(["[name=gender] option:selected").text());
    });
}
```

(and in the form)

```
<input type="hidden" name="fullGender" id="fullGender"/>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the hidden field; doing it server side is better in this case.